# How to show image from folder using url

Tags: php, html, file-upload

i am using php code for creating folder  at run time where i am storing some images.

when i try to accecss these image it does not show images asa well as folder name   using appropriate URL.

but when i logedin using cpanel it shows  folder name.

Here is my code

```
  $dir="1buyerseller";
         $desired_dir=$email;
        $filename=  $dir.'/'.$email.'/'.$file_name;
        //echo $filename;
        $query="INSERT into  buysellsetailads (id,ads,cid) VALUES('seller','$filename','$cid'); ";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$dir/$desired_dir", 0700);       // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$dir/$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
               move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$dir/$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$dir/$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
         mysql_query($query);           
        }
```

Using this code i am creating folder and uploding image into this folder.
whnen i try like this

```
http://www.xpokerala.com/admin/1square/
```

Here  some folder are showing which created hardcoded but dyanamic created not showing

Why i dondt no.

How can i resolve this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$query="INSERT into  buysellsetailads (id,ads,cid) VALUES('seller','$filename','$cid'); ";`

should this be `buysellretailads`?

Comment: i did not get your mean by this

Comment: Is it possible that you misspelt the table name?